# Customize mplfinance plot python

Tags: python, mplfinance

I trying to change the color of filled shape and add image logo on the top left and price on the right but I don't want price and logo overlapping chart at self, is there is way to move it up?

My code:

```
 def chartBuilber(self):
    df: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self.priceHistory()).fillna(method="backfill")
    df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    df = df.astype(float)


    market_colors = mpf.make_marketcolors(
        base_mpf_style="yahoo"
    )
    rc = {
        "axes.labelcolor": "none",
        "axes.spines.bottom": True,
        "axes.spines.left": False,
        "axes.spines.right": False,
        "axes.spines.top": False,
        "font.size": 12,
    }

    styles = mpf.make_mpf_style(
        base_mpf_style="nightclouds",
        marketcolors=market_colors,
        gridstyle="",
        rc=rc
    )

    mpf.plot(df, type='line',
             title='Test',
             linecolor='#00ff00',
             style=styles,
             volume=True,
             figsize=(18, 12),
             figscale=0.5,
             fill_between=df['Close'].values,
             tight_layout=True,
             scale_padding={'left': 0.5, 'top': 5, 'right': 0.7, 'bottom': 1})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the color of the fill, you can specify `fill_between` as a `dict` (instead of list of numbers).  In the dict you must specify `y1=` for the y values (for example, in your case, `y1=df['Close'].values`).  Then add also to the dict `facecolor=` the color you want for the fill.  Thus, something like:

```py
mpf.plot(df,...,fill_between=dict(y1=df['Close'].values`,facecolor='lime'),...)
```

To get some extra room at the top of the plot, you can use kwarg `ylim=` specifying a two-element tuple or list (ymin,ymax) where ymax is enough larger than your maximum y-value to give you the amount of space your desire.

Comment: What about image? I am just trying to create something like this https://ibb.co/R4gyLGf.